# How to automatically update View Model when CoreData changes in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm, core-data

**Context**

I have an `App` using `SwiftUI` and `CoreData`. For displaying the `Data` and updating it automatically when changes appear in the `Model`, `SwiftUI` provides the `@FetchRequest` `Property Wrapper`, that can be used in `Views`.

However, I would like to have a `ViewModel` that manages the `Data` stored in `CoreData` and can be used by `Views` through the `@Published` `Property Wrapper`. But I have difficulties implementing a solution, that also updates automatically to changes in `CoreData`.

---

**Code**

```swift
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var filteredEntities: [Entity]

    init() {
        // Load all Entities from CoreData, filter and assign them to filteredEntities.
        // Also make sure, that when CoreData changes, the step above gets repeated.
    }
}
```

---

**Questions**

- Is this possible and was `SwiftUI` & `MVVM` designed for this?
- How can I achieve the goal described above?

Comment: You need to listen to notifications from your NSManagedObjectContext to keep your data up to date, see for example [this article](https://www.donnywals.com/responding-to-changes-in-a-managed-object-context/) or use a solution where NSFetchedResultsController handles it for you, there should be several articles available about how to do it.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/TimmysApp/CoreDataStruct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for view model objects in SwiftUI. The View struct holds the view data and the property wrappers makes it behave like an object. This gives you the speed of value types with the benefits of reference types, i.e. best of both worlds. If you attempt to use your own view model object you'll run into the kind of object consistency issues that SwiftUI was designed to eliminate.

The property wrapper for core data is [@FetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I would like to implement some basic filtering, sorting, grouping, etc. When having a separate `@FetchRequest` in every `View`, I have to repeat this `Logic` for every `View`. Or do you have an idea on `Best Practices` in this case?

Comment: Use `@SectionedFetchRequest` for the grouping, `predicate` param for the filtering and `sortDescriptors` param for the sorting. I recommend taking a look at WWDC 2019 Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI that introduces SectionedFetchRequest.

Comment: I think you meant WWDC 2021?